# Azure function with Swashbuckle, unable to get $(date) in API swagger schema for date type

Tags: asp.net, date, azure-functions, formatting, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

## I am using SwashBuckle with Azure function ( dotnet 6 )

### [Entity Class]

```
   public DateOnly startDate { get; set; }
```

---

### Swagger showing date in API schema as below :

```
startDate   dateOnly{
year    integer($int32)
month   integer($int32)
day integer($int32)
dayOfWeek   integer($int32)
default: 0
Enum:
Array [ 7 ]
dayOfYear   integer($int32)
dayNumber   integer($int32)
}
```

### Expected :

```
startDate string($date)
```

Need some assistance,

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by customizing the dates by inheriting the IsoDateTimeConverter class and by using API conventions.

**Customizing the date formats**

Sample date formats

```
 public  class myclass: IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            public myCustomFormat(string format)
            {
                DateTimeFormat = format;
            }
        }
```

```
    public class DateConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
        {
            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(value.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd"));
            }

            public override DateTime ReadJson(JsonReader rdr, Type objectType, DateTime myValue, bool hasValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                return DateTime.ParseExact(rdr.Value.ToString(), "YYYY-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
```

And to avoid errors in changing the date format with JSON serializer.

```
var myDate = new DateTime(2023, 23, 1, 30, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

var myDate = new DateTime(2023, 23, 1, 30, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

References taken from

[API Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Date Formats-rfc3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) - Thanks to Klyne for the blog